# Passing data and retrieving data via same struct using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, struct

I need to read a file from a separate thread, to avoid hiccups in the flow of my opengl program. I already do that for loading textures and blending them using global variables, that works fine.

However now I need some separate threads to read small data files.

I have created a `struct`, which basically contains 2 args and 1 result.

It seems I can't do that or I got it wrong somewhere (or in many places)

Here is the sample code of my non proof of concept:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define content_file "/home/tias/content.txt" //this file contains "foobar!!"

typedef struct {
    int* reading;     // 0 = not reading , 1 = reading , 2 = finished reading
    char* content;    // content of the file
    char* file;       // file to read
} struct_file_content;

struct_file_content first_file;

void *thread_read_file ( void* data ) {

    struct_file_content *thisdata = (struct_file_content*) data;
    long length;
  int i = 0;
  char readchar;
  char * thiscontent = 0;
    int reading_finished = 2;
    int *ptr_to_reading_finished = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    ptr_to_reading_finished = &reading_finished;

    fprintf(stdout,"thread_Read_file called with file: %s and reading: %u\n",(*thisdata).file,*(*thisdata).reading);

    FILE * f = fopen ((*thisdata).file, "r");

    if (f) {
    fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell (f);
    fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    if (length > 39) {
      fprintf(stderr,"file %s is too big\n",(*thisdata).file);
      exit (1);
    }
        thiscontent = (char*) malloc (length*sizeof(char));
        if ( thiscontent ) {
            fread (thiscontent, 1, length, f);
        }
    fclose (f);
        thisdata->content = thiscontent;
  } else {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot read file %s\n",(*thisdata).file);
    exit (1);
  }

    sleep(1);

    thisdata->reading = ptr_to_reading_finished;

    fprintf(stdout,"finished reading: %u\n",*(*thisdata).reading);
    fprintf(stdout,"content: %s\n",thiscontent);

  pthread_exit(NULL);
  return NULL;
}

main()
{
    pthread_t thread1;
    int filename_length = strlen(content_file);
    int rfinish = 2;
    int rbegin  = 1;

    first_file.reading = (int*)  malloc(sizeof(int));
    first_file.file    = (char*) malloc((filename_length+1)*sizeof(char));
    first_file.reading = &rbegin;
    strcpy(first_file.file,content_file);

  pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, thread_read_file, (void*) &first_file);

    while ( *(first_file.reading) != 2 ) {  
        fprintf(stdout,"still reading, reading: %u\n",*(first_file.reading));
        sleep(1);
    }

    fprintf(stdout,"exited control loop with file: %s, reading: %u, content: %s\n",first_file.file, *(first_file.reading), first_file.content);
}
```

Here's the result:

```
~/repository/thread/test$ ./tt
still reading, reading: 1
thread_Read_file called with file: /home/tias/content.txt and reading: 1
still reading, reading: 1
still reading, reading: 1
still reading, reading: 1
finished reading: 2
content: foobar!!

still reading, reading: 0
still reading, reading: 0
```

I was expecting `reading = 2` to get out of the loop, instead it is 0.

Any idea on what I have to modify to make it work?

I have read about mutex and so, may be it is the way?

I had found my solution elegant and not working, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `%d` to print an `int`, not `%u`. Also, change `first_file.reading = (int*)  malloc(sizeof(int));` to `first_file.reading = calloc(1, sizeof(int));`

Comment: I did that and same thing happens.

Comment: None of this is atomic, and none of this is protected with a mutex. This code is racy as can be, hence undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef struct {
    int* reading;     // 0 = not reading , 1 = reading , 2 = finished reading
    char* content;    // content of the file
    char* file;       // file to read
} struct_file_content;
```

Why is `reading` a pointer type? It is used in the code as a flag, there is absolutely no need to make it a pointer, especially given that you dynamically allocate memory for this structure field. It complicates the design and is unnecessary. Go ahead and make that an `int`, not a pointer:

```
typedef struct {
    int reading;     // 0 = not reading , 1 = reading , 2 = finished reading
    char *content;    // content of the file
    char *file;       // file to read
} struct_file_content;
```

This simplifies the code in `main()` used to set up `first_file`:

```
first_file.reading = 1;
first_file.content = NULL;
first_file.file = content_file;
```

Note that there is no need to have `first_file.file` be dynamically allocated memory, since you know the file name (and size) at compile time. Keep things simple.

Next, you ignore a possible error return value from `pthread_create(3)`. It returns non-zero in case of failure, and you should check for that. Something like this will do:

```
pthread_t thread1;
int thread_res = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread_read_file, &first_file);
if (thread_res != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create(3) error: %s\n", strerror(thread_res));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The code to wait for reading to finish is buggy and racy, you need to either synchronize access to the `reading` field of `struct_file_content` with a mutex, or properly wait for the thread to terminate before accessing the `first_file` again. Since the code does nothing but wait for the thread, `pthread_join(3)` is a much more reasonable choice here. You'd do something like:

```
int join_res = pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
if (join_res != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "pthread_join(3) error: %s\n", strerror(join_res));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Inside `thread_read_file()`, you probably want `pthread_exit(3)` when handling errors instead of `exit(2)`, since the latter will terminate the entire process, not just the local thread. You also need to handle `malloc(3)` errors.

Here's the code with all of these issues addressed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define content_file "/home/tias/content.txt" //this file contains "foobar!!"

typedef struct {
    int reading;     // 0 = not reading , 1 = reading , 2 = finished reading
    char *content;   // content of the file
    char *file;      // file to read
} struct_file_content;

struct_file_content first_file;

void *thread_read_file(void *data) {
    struct_file_content *thisdata = data;

    long length;
    char *thiscontent = NULL;

    fprintf(stdout,"thread_Read_file called with file: %s and reading: %u\n", thisdata->file, thisdata->reading);

    FILE *f = fopen (thisdata->file, "r");

    if (f) {
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        length = ftell(f);
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        if (length > 39) {
            fprintf(stderr,"file %s is too big\n", thisdata->file);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        thiscontent = malloc(length);

        if (thiscontent) {
            fread(thiscontent, 1, length, f);
        } else {
            perror("malloc(3) error");
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        fclose(f);
        thisdata->content = thiscontent;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file %s\n", thisdata->file);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    thisdata->reading = 2;

    fprintf(stdout, "finished reading: %u\n", thisdata->reading);
    fprintf(stdout, "content: %s\n", thiscontent);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    first_file.reading = 1;
    first_file.content = NULL;
    first_file.file = content_file;

    pthread_t thread1;
    int thread_res = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread_read_file, &first_file);
    if (thread_res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create(3) error: %s\n", strerror(thread_res));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int join_res = pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    if (join_res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_join(3) error: %s\n", strerror(join_res));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "Read file %s, reading: %u, content: %s\n", first_file.file, first_file.reading, first_file.content);

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

From the comments, it seems like you want to do some additional processing and periodically test (at your convenience) whether the thread is done reading. Your approach of using a flag to test for termination is mostly correct, but you should synchronize access to the `reading` field of `struct_file_content` to make sure that you always get consistent values. As such, I suggest adding a mutex to `struct_file_content` that is used to control concurrent access to the `reading` field. You should lock the mutex every time you need to read or update `reading`.

So, the structure definition becomes:

```
typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t read_mutex; // synchronize access to reading flag
    int reading;     // 0 = not reading , 1 = reading , 2 = finished reading
    char *content;   // content of the file
    char *file;      // file to read
} struct_file_content;
```

Then, as part of initializing `struct_file_content`, you need to remember to initialize the mutex. Here's how you'd do it in `main()`:

```
int mutex_err = pthread_mutex_init(&first_file.read_mutex, NULL);

if (mutex_err != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "pthread_mutex_init(3) error: %s\n", strerror(mutex_err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

first_file.reading = 1;
first_file.content = NULL;
first_file.file = content_file;
```

Now, the loop in `main()` simply locks the mutex, checks the status of the `reading` field (breaking out if it is equal to 2), and unlocks the mutex. Something like:

```
int read_done = 0;
while (!read_done) {

    mutex_err = pthread_mutex_lock(&first_file.read_mutex);
    if (mutex_err != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_mutex_lock(3) error: %s\n", strerror(mutex_err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Reading is finished when first_file.reading == 2 */
    read_done = (first_file.reading == 2);

    if (first_file.reading != 2)
        printf("Still reading, reading: %u\n", first_file.reading);

    mutex_err = pthread_mutex_unlock(&first_file.read_mutex);
    if (mutex_err != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_mutex_unlock(3) error: %s\n", strerror(mutex_err));
    }
}
```

Of course, you also need to update the thread function to lock the mutex before modifying `reading`:

```
void *thread_read_file(void *data) {

    struct_file_content *thisdata = data;
    int mutex_res;
    long length;
    char *thiscontent = NULL;

    mutex_res = pthread_mutex_lock(&thisdata->read_mutex);
    if (mutex_res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "thread_read_file() failed to acquire mutex: %s\n", strerror(mutex_res));
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "thread_read_file() called with file: %s and reading: %u\n", thisdata->file, thisdata->reading);

    mutex_res = pthread_mutex_unlock(&thisdata->read_mutex);
    if (mutex_res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "thread_read_file() failed to release mutex: %s\n", strerror(mutex_res));
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    FILE *f = fopen(thisdata->file, "r");

    if (f) {
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        length = ftell(f);
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);

        if (length > 39) {
            fprintf(stderr, "file %s is too big\n", thisdata->file);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        thiscontent = malloc(length);

        if (thiscontent) {
            fread(thiscontent, 1, length, f);
        } else {
            perror("malloc(3) error");
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        fclose(f);
        thisdata->content = thiscontent;

    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file %s\n", thisdata->file);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    mutex_res = pthread_mutex_lock(&thisdata->read_mutex);
    if (mutex_res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "thread_read_file() failed to acquire mutex: %s\n", strerror(mutex_res));
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    thisdata->reading = 2;
    fprintf(stdout, "finished reading: %u\n", thisdata->reading);

    mutex_res = pthread_mutex_unlock(&thisdata->read_mutex);
    if (mutex_res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "thread_read_file() failed to release mutex: %s\n", strerror(mutex_res));
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "content: %s\n", thiscontent);

    return NULL;
}
```

That should be enough. Here's the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define content_file "/home/tias/content.txt" //this file contains "foobar!!"

typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t read_mutex; // synchronize access to reading flag
    int reading;     // 0 = not reading , 1 = reading , 2 = finished reading
    char *content;   // content of the file
    char *file;      // file to read
} struct_file_content;

struct_file_content first_file;

void *thread_read_file(void *data) {

    struct_file_content *thisdata = data;
    int mutex_res;
    long length;
    char *thiscontent = NULL;

    mutex_res = pthread_mutex_lock(&thisdata->read_mutex);
    if (mutex_res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "thread_read_file() failed to acquire mutex: %s\n", strerror(mutex_res));
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "thread_read_file() called with file: %s and reading: %u\n", thisdata->file, thisdata->reading);

    mutex_res = pthread_mutex_unlock(&thisdata->read_mutex);
    if (mutex_res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "thread_read_file() failed to release mutex: %s\n", strerror(mutex_res));
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    FILE *f = fopen(thisdata->file, "r");

    if (f) {
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        length = ftell(f);
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);

        if (length > 39) {
            fprintf(stderr, "file %s is too big\n", thisdata->file);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        thiscontent = malloc(length);

        if (thiscontent) {
            fread(thiscontent, 1, length, f);
        } else {
            perror("malloc(3) error");
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        fclose(f);
        thisdata->content = thiscontent;

    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file %s\n", thisdata->file);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    mutex_res = pthread_mutex_lock(&thisdata->read_mutex);
    if (mutex_res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "thread_read_file() failed to acquire mutex: %s\n", strerror(mutex_res));
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    thisdata->reading = 2;
    fprintf(stdout, "finished reading: %u\n", thisdata->reading);

    mutex_res = pthread_mutex_unlock(&thisdata->read_mutex);
    if (mutex_res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "thread_read_file() failed to release mutex: %s\n", strerror(mutex_res));
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "content: %s\n", thiscontent);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {

    int mutex_err = pthread_mutex_init(&first_file.read_mutex, NULL);

    if (mutex_err != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_mutex_init(3) error: %s\n", strerror(mutex_err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    first_file.reading = 1;
    first_file.content = NULL;
    first_file.file = content_file;

    pthread_t thread1;
    int thread_res = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread_read_file, &first_file);
    if (thread_res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create(3) error: %s\n", strerror(thread_res));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int read_done = 0;
    while (!read_done) {

        mutex_err = pthread_mutex_lock(&first_file.read_mutex);
        if (mutex_err != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "pthread_mutex_lock(3) error: %s\n", strerror(mutex_err));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* Reading is finished when first_file.reading == 2 */
        read_done = (first_file.reading == 2);

        if (first_file.reading != 2)
            printf("Still reading, reading: %u\n", first_file.reading);

        mutex_err = pthread_mutex_unlock(&first_file.read_mutex);
        if (mutex_err != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "pthread_mutex_unlock(3) error: %s\n", strerror(mutex_err));
        }
    }

    /* Here we don't need to lock because the thread has finished and no other thread is
     * using this struct
     */

    fprintf(stdout, "Read file %s, reading: %u, content: %s\n", first_file.file, first_file.reading, first_file.content);

    free(first_file.content);
    mutex_err = pthread_mutex_destroy(&first_file.read_mutex);
    if (mutex_err != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Error destroying mutex: %s\n", strerror(mutex_err));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I added cleanup code in the end of `main()`. Even though it is not necessary (because the program is about to terminate), it is there to make sure you don't forget what kind of cleanup needs to be done once a thread terminates.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but you use join_res = pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
this will block upon completion of the thread, which is exactly what I want to avoid. I have commented the join_res part with the pthread_join and used instead:
        while ( first_file.reading != 2 ) {
          fprintf(stdout,"still reading\n");
          sleep(1);
        }
is there any problem doing so  ?

Comment: @MathiasLienard While it may work in practice, it's not a good approach because reading and writing an integer structure field are not necessarily atomic operations. You should protect it with a mutex to ensure that you always see a consistent value in `first_file.reading`. I am going to update my answer to show how you can do this.

Comment: @MathiasLienard See the updated answer. I ran a small test and it seems to be working.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I have green checked your answer, where's the send_a_fresh_beer button ?

Comment: @MathiasLienard Hehe, thanks :) Glad I could help! I wish you the best of luck and success with your project.